# "specific case" object that stands for "any object" : is it a good idea ?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I got tired of doing (more or less) this in my rails controllers :

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @category = Category.find( params[:category_id] ) if params[:category_id].present?
    scope = @category ? @category.things : Thing.scoped
    @things = scope.order( :title )
  end
end
```

...wich also leads to a lot of conditionals in the template if `@category` is absent.

I had this idea (a variation on the `NullObject` pattern) :

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.one_or_any( id )
    where( id: id ).first || any_category
  end

  def self.any_category
    @any_category ||= begin
      new( title: "Any category" ) do |generic|
        generic.instance_eval{ def things ; Thing.scoped end }
        generic.readonly!
        generic.freeze
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which would in turn allow me to do :

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @category = Category.one_or_any( params[:category_id] )
    @things   = @category.things.order( :title )
  end
end
```

... and to get rid of category-related conditionals in the template.

**I Just wonder if this is a good idea, and if it has drawbacks i don't see yet. Thoughts ?**

*Note : Of course the actual implementation can be different (use a specific subclass of `Category` instead of extending an instance, for example - or even using a decorator).*

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to keep it as simple as possible. Instead of multiple in-line conditionals or a weird abstraction, I think a single full-fledged indented conditional makes things very clear. There are two scenarios, write two branches:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:category_id].present? 
      @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
      @things = @category.things
    else
      @category = nil
      @things = Thing.scoped
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ok, but the question was more about the "generic object" idea. I'd like to avoid that `@category = nil` because it involves a view riddled with conditionals - if i had an object that quacks like a category, it would be better